# zend framework2においてのPDF出力方法をご教示願います

Tags: php, zend-framework

zendframework2で構築されているWEBシステムの改修を実施したいのですが、WEBページ（複数画像あり）上にPDF出力ボタンを配置し、それを押下するとPDFが出力される方法をどなたかご教示願います。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

【備考】
システムOS：WindowsServer2012R2
言語：PHP5.6.3(ZendFramework2)
DB：Postgres

Comment: 利用を想定されている OS は Windows Server でしょうか、Linux でしょうか。
また、WEB システムに利用されている主な言語などの情報があると、的確な答えが得られると思います。

Comment: Shironeさま
助言ありがとうございます。質問内容に追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

この回答は、出力したいPDFが動的であり、PDFファイルを静的に配置するだけでは対応できない状況を想定しています。また、HTMLをPDFに変換する方法になりますので、ZF2側では、出力したいPDFの元となるページを用意しておくことが前提条件となります。

まず、PHPはネイティブでPDFを生成できます。
http://php.net/manual/ja/book.pdf.php

しかしこの方法は(当然ですが)PHPでしか使えず、実装も手間かと思います。

外部ライブラリを用いたPDFの生成は、主にHTMLをPDFに変換する方式を採用しています。以下は例です。
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
https://github.com/tcpdf-clone/tcpdf

また、PhantomJSを使えば、言語やフレームワークを問わずに、HTMLをPDFに変換することが出来ます。
http://phantomjs.org/

DomPDFやTCPDFはPHPのプロセス上でHTMLやCSSを解析してPDFを生成(JSは動かない)しますが、PhantomJSはPhantomJS上のプロセスで、飽くまでブラウザとしてHTMLにアクセスしてPDFを生成(JSは動く)します。

以下、PhantomJS公式サイトの http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html に記載された
"Beside PNG format, PhantomJS supports JPEG, GIF, and PDF."
の方法になります。ZF2側で意識すべきは、最後のPHPサンブル箇所になります。

まず、お使いのOS用のPhantomJSを http://phantomjs.org/download.html からDLします。バスは必要に応じて通して下さい。例えばMacの場合だと、DLしたzipファイル内の phantomjs-{VERSION}-macosx/bin/phantomjs が必要なファイルなので、このファイルを /usr/local/bin/ などに移動します。以下のようにバージョンの確認ができればOKです。

```
$ phantomjs -v
2.0.0
```

次に https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js をDLします。curlやwget、あるいはブラウザから https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ariya/phantomjs/master/examples/rasterize.js を保存します。

以上で準備は完了です。PhantomJSでPDFを作成、保存します。以下のコマンドは、DLした rasterize.js がある場所で実行して下さい。

```
$ phantomjs rasterize.js http://example.com/ example.com.pdf
```

コマンドを実行した場所に "example.com.pdf" が作成され、内容が http://example.com/ になっていれば正しく実行されています。

最後に、この方法をPHPで実行するサンプルが、以下になります。

```
<?php

$pdf = uniqid().'.pdf';
exec('phantomjs rasterize.js http://example.com/ '.$pdf);

header('Content-type:application/pdf');
echo file_get_contents($pdf);
unlink($pdf);
```

Comment: mamorさま

早々のご教示、感謝いたします。

実際にはWEBページをそのままPDF化するといったわけではないのですが（言葉足らずで申し訳ございません）、ひとまず上記を試みたいと思います。

つきましては、大変恐れ入りますが、より詳細な手順をご教示していただけないでしょうか？

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 手順は書いたとおりなので、ダウンロードURL等を書き足しました。「WEBページをそのままというわけではない。」ということですので解決に至らないかもしれませんが、もし「WEBページの一部」であるならば、そのWEBページの一部を出力するページを作成した上でキャプチャするのも手段の一つかなと思います。PHPの機能でもPDFの生成は出来ますが、PhantomJSを用いた方法と比べると少々手間かなと思います。

Comment: 他の方法も含めて、いろいろと編集してみました。

Comment: mamorさま
追加のご教示ありがとうございます。
またもし何か質問が挙がってきましたらご連絡させていただきます。
その際は、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

@mamor さんと同様のもので Snappy (wkhtmltopdf) というものがあります。

https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy

もし `$ composer` が使えない環境で行う場合は

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

だけでもいいと思います。(ちなみに wkhtmltopdf はコマンドとして使えます)

`Phantom.js` と同じように、 web ページのコンテンツによって情報が欠落したり、レンダリング結果に差異がありますので、ご注意ください。

Comment: Shironeさま
ご教示、感謝いたします。試用したいと思います。