# html表示内容をPDFへ変換したい

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

現在表示しているHTMLの表示をPDFへ変換したいです。

PHPの”fpdf”で試みるも、指定したテキストもしくはセル等をPHPで宣言しないと不可な様子です。 
(それでは手間がかかり逆に意味がありません・・。)

表示している内容をワンクリックでPDF変換できるようにするには、どういった方法がありますか？ 
もしJavascript側で可能でしたら方法は特に問いません、宜しくお願いします・・。

● fpdfの公式ページ 
http://www.fpdf.org/

=======================追記=========================

mpdfでpdfに成功しました。
PHPで生成したページをpdf化したいのですが、やはりその場合実行された状態で
表示ができません。
表示しているページを変換かけたいのですが、何か方法はありませんか？

Comment: GoogleChromeなどの印刷機能で任意のページをPDFに保存することができますが、そうではなく、あなたが製作しているWebサイトの機能としてPDFダウンロード機能をユーザーに提供したいということでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
印刷機能ではなく、任意のボタンを設置してそのボタンのクリック時にpdfへ変換したい仕様です。
クリック時にPHPファイルの指定をしておけばいけると思いますが、そのPHPファイルの記述ともしくはPHPプラグインで何を使ったらいいかわからない状況です・・。
言葉足らずすみません。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/19400

Answer (score 2):

Javascript でというと、[jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) というライブラリがDOM要素からのPDF生成をサポートしているようです。ただサイト上のサンプルで「HTML Renderer」を見てみると、CSSが適用されないようです。

html2canvas などを使って一旦画像に変換し、それをPDFに埋め込むというやり方も。

- [JavascriptでPDF作成 - 空飛ぶ](http://ebifly.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/06/004742)

PHPの場合、dompdfやtcpdfといったPHPでHTMLの解析から行うライブラリを使う方法と、ブラウザのレンダリングエンジンを利用したPhantomJSやwkhtmltopdfを使う方法があります。後者の場合はPHPとは別にプログラムをインストールする必要があるため、レンタルサーバー等では難しいかもしれません。

- [php - zend framework2においてのPDF出力方法をご教示願います - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/6038/8000)
- [PHPでPDFを作成する時はwkhtmltopdf + snappyで戦え - Qiita](http://qiita.com/morisuke/items/b9c18dcba99ba6501d6e)

Answer (score -1):

JavaでそういうHtmlからPDFへの変換は実現できます、[Spire.PDF for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/pdf-for-java-free.html)といったコンポーネントを使って簡単に完成します。

```java
import com.spire.pdf.graphics.PdfMargins;
import com.spire.pdf.htmlconverter.qt.HtmlConverter;
import com.spire.pdf.htmlconverter.qt.Size;

public class HtmltoPDF
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //define the HTML link and result PDF
        String url = "https://www.xxxxxxx.com/";
        String fileName = "Result.pdf";
        //Set the plugin path
        String pluginPath = "D:/Qt/plugins_32";
        HtmlConverter.setPluginPath(pluginPath);
        //convert HTML to PDF and set the size of the result PDF page
        HtmlConverter.convert(url, fileName, true, 1000000, new Size(600f, 900f), new PdfMargins(0));
    }
}
```

必要なコードは以上です、また他の形式も変換可能です。